# Stepping through objects returned from Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm storing a list of objects in Google Firebase. I'm wanting to process each of those objects and store them in an array:

```
firebase.database().ref('trainingsets').once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {

                var trainingSets: TrainingSet[] = [];
                console.log(snapshot.val());   // Console 1

                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    console.log("child=" + child);  // Console 2
                    trainingSets.push(child);
                });

                console.log(trainingSets);  // Console 3

                this.trainingSets = trainingSets;
                this.trainingSetsChanged.next(this.trainingSets.slice());

            });
```

TrainingSet is a model which reflects each of the objects that are stored in Firebase:

```
export class TrainingSet {

    /**
     * Unique Identifier of this set
     */
    id:number;

    name:string;
    type: string;
    description: string;

}
```

My data is successfully retrieved. At comment Console 1 I see an Object which has two sub-objects which contain my data. However at Console 2, I just get empty objects and at Console 3 I have an array containing the right number of elements, but with elements that are titled "V" which have a bunch of strange sub items in them. I'm not sure what those actually are.

Can anyone advise me what the best way to do this is? I don't really need an array, if I could properly step through the object tree I could probably just use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

```
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    console.log(child.val());
                    trainingSets.push(child.val());
                });
```

I needed to call the val function on the child.